# Does $\sum r$ mean the same as $\sum_{r=1}^n r\;$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, notation

Does a sum with no limits e.g.
$$\sum r$$ mean the same as $$\sum_{r=1}^n r$$ for a sum $1 + 2 + \cdots + n$?

Comment: A sum written like this will normally be contextual, so we can't really say exactly what it means without knowing where you saw it and what was being discussed. Can you give more information?

Comment: It depends on the context. A sum should always have limits, $\sum_{j = a}^b x_j$. Alternatively, one can sum over an index family, as in $\sum_{j \in \mathcal J} x_j$, but special care has to be taken when this family is infinite (-> summable family). You leave away the limits only when it is clear from the context what is meant.

Comment: For example if you're writing a step of working 1 + 2 + ... + n = sum notation, do you have to still write the limits?

Comment: I suppose you don't _have_ to but I would personally find the notation $1 + 2 + \dots + n = \sum r$ to be bad practice. My personal preference for writing limits is that you should always write them in the sum unless they happen to be too complex to write neatly or succinctly as subscripts/superscripts. At the end of the day though that kind of thing is more a matter of taste.

Comment: @icantcode: If you're asking for *advice* about writing unambiguous notation, then: You can do (more-or-less) whatever you think best serves your presentation, so long as you explain any unconventional notation to the reader. In particular, if in some long proof or other discussion, all of your summations are over $i=1, \ldots, n$, then it's perfectly valid (and likely welcome) to say "For the duration, I'll reduce visual clutter by abbreviating '$\sum_{i=1}^n$' as '$\sum$'." However, you can't expect someone who sees `$\sum$` without such a disclaimer to automatically know what you mean.